# Display: Flex not producing content under it

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Why is the paragraph in the second column being produced on the right of the heading rather than below it? I used `display: flex` to align the content in middle and center but I want the new elements within the column to be stacked under the previous element.

```css
main{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #4b53ff, #9e63ff);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
}
main .row{
    width: 65vw;
    height: 60vh;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.col1{
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    
}
.col2{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #7633e5, #178ee0);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    width:  100%;
}
p{
  font-size:11px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="d-flex align-items-center ">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-sm-4 col1  d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <h2 class="block">login</h2>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col2 d-flex align-items-center ">
                    <h2 class="d-block justify-content-center">Random heading</h2>
                    <p class="d-block justify-content-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run your code in the snippet I see that `p` is placed below `h2`. However they're not centered, and as I see you use much more classes than you shown in CSS.

Comment: I've edited it, check again, please.

Comment: Now I see. Let me look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `flex-direction: column;` style to `col2` class.

Default `flex-direction` value is `row`, that's why it places them in a row in `col2`. `col1` has only one element that's why you don't see that it is also a row.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Comment: But the content is no longer vertically aligned in center after setting flex direction to column,

Comment: When you change direction from `row` to `column` you need to swap `align-items` with `justify-content`. So if it was `align-items: center` it will be `justify-content: center` and vice-versa.

Comment: I suggest you to remove align-items/justify-content classes and use them as styles in CSS, it will make your code cleaner and will be easier to work with styles.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your second div:

```
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

The last rule will center the `div` and `p`.
Hope it helped.